# Swift & Parse.com find by specific column not ID

Tags: swift, parse-platform

Reference: http://blog.parse.com/2014/06/06/building-apps-with-parse-and-swift/

I'm trying to find a columns value: userPassword, based in the userName column. Using the above reference from Parse it shows that to get data from parse you should use:

```
 var query = PFQuery(className: "GameScore")
 query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(gameScore.objectId) {
 (scoreAgain: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
  if !error {
    NSLog("%@", scoreAgain.objectForKey("playerName") as NSString)
  } else {
    NSLog("%@", error)
  } 
 }
```

However, as you can see it is looking for (gameScore.objectId) - The problem is I do not know this value as the user isnt entering a complex parse generated ID. They're entering their chosen username. In the rows I have userName and Password set. How do I search the rows for the userPassword so I can verify it based on their specified userName.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you querying the database for a username and password. Adding a new user is very simple with Parse. Taken directly from their docs:

---

## Query User table on Parse

You can query the user table first, using a PFQuery:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:username];
```

## Adding New User

The idea of user accounts that let people access their information and share it with others in a secure manner is at the core of any social app. Whether your app creates its own sharing environment or integrates with existing social networks, you will need to add functionality to let people manage their accounts in your app.

We provide a specialized user class called PFUser that automatically handles much of the functionality required for user account management.

First make sure to include our SDK libraries from your .h file:

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
```

Then add this code into your app, for example in the viewDidLoad method (or inside another method that gets called when you run your app):

```
    func myMethod() {
    var user = PFUser()
    user.username = "myUsername"
    user.password = "myPassword"
    user.email = "email@example.com"
    // other fields can be set just like with PFObject
    user["phone"] = "415-392-0202"

   user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
     (succeeded: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
     if error == nil {
       // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
     } else {
       let errorString = error.userInfo["error"] as NSString
       // Show the errorString somewhere and let the user try again.
     }
  }
}
```

This call will asynchronously create a new user in your Parse app. Before it does this, it checks to make sure that both the username and email are unique. It also securely hashes the password in the cloud.

You can learn more about Users, including how to verify emails and handle read and write permissions to data, by visiting our docs.

Run your app. A new object of the class User will be sent to the Parse Cloud and saved. When you're ready, click the button below to test if a User was created.

## Further

I created a tutorial about connecting to parse if you still wish to go down the route of querying the server manually:

http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/swift-create-user-sign-up-based-app-with-parse-com-using-pfuser/

Comment: That is adding a new user, How do I tell if there is already one there?